# Is there a better way in EF core for my query (join parent table only because of parent key)?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core and I still struggle sometimes on how I should load data.

In SQL I would build my query like this:

```
SELECT i.Id, i.HeaderSliderPageId, i.Active, i.ImageURL, i.Content, i.SortOrder
FROM headersliderimage i
RIGHT JOIN headersliderpage p on p.Id = i.HeaderSliderPageId
WHERE p.WebpageId = 1
```

Now in ef core I am using this

```
var data =  from i in db.HeaderSliderImage
join p in db.HeaderSliderPage.Where(p => p.WebpageId == webpageId) on i.HeaderSliderPageId equals p.Id
select i;
```

This works, but I am not sure if this is the way to go. Or if I should work with 'Incude'. but i am only referencing the parant table because of the Id.

Is my approach ok or are there better ways to solve this?
Thanks for any help on that matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the mapping between the two tables One - to - Many?

You actually don't need to manually join the tables - EF will do that for you. So, you can write the following:

```
db.HeaderSliderImage
  .Where(image => image.HeaderSliderPage.WebpageId == webpageId)
  .ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ventsislav for pointiong me into the right direction!!!
I did not have a navigation property on the "HeaderSliderImage" table. Once I added that it worked with your code without manually joing the tables! Thank you!!